Next.js: Invalid next.config.js options with next-pwa
I'm working on a Next.js project where I'm trying to integrate Progressive Web App (PWA) functionality using the next-pwa package. However, I'm encountering an issue with invalid options in my next.config.js file.
code snippet:
const withPWA = require('next-pwa');
const runtimeCaching = require('next-pwa/cache');
module.exports = withPWA({
pwa: {
dest: 'public',
register: true,
runtimeCaching,
},
Additional Information:
Next.js version: 14.1.0
Environment: Development
Node.js version: [20]
Installed next-pwa package.
Configured next.config.js file to include PWA options.
Started development server.
Error Message :
⚠ Invalid next.config.js options detected:
⚠ Unrecognized key(s) in object: '0', '1', '2', ..., '23'
Expected Outcome:
I expect the PWA configuration to be applied correctly without encountering any invalid options error.

Go to the Application tab in the devtools and select the manifest file. It'll show you the errors and warnings, and below that, it'll show you the Installability section. The error highlighted in the Installability section is the first thing preventing the desired PWA behaviour.
